# ABPFRAMWORK couldn't determinate version of @abp/ng.schematics

Tags: abp

I'm facing an error when using the command: `abp generate-proxy`

ABP Framework version: **Version 4.0.0 (Stable)**

User Interface: **Angular**

Steps needed to reproduce the problem: Executing the command `abp generate-proxy`

Exception message:

> please double chek  the URL in the source project environment and make
> sure you application is up and running

In addition, how can I fix the warning:

> Couldn't determinate version of "@abp/ng.schematics" package.

> [WRN] Couldn't determinate version of "@abp/ng.schematics" package.

> [Error] [API NOT AVAILABLE]please double chek  the URL in the source project environment and make sure you application is up and running

Comment: check your environment: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-Setup-Environment?UI=NG&DB=EF&Tiered=No

Comment: I am also facing the same error with generating abp proxies. is there any fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try specifying the URL parameter; e.g.,

```
abp generate-proxy -t ng -m identity -u https://localhost:yourportnumber
```

This worked for me.